# gcc compiler default options when calling gcc trough CC, cross compiling

Tags: cross-compiling, cc

I am looking for a flag which would tell me what are the default options of the gcc compiler. For example for cray compiler that is "-hdisplay_opt" I need gcc equivalent for that. I am using gcc/4.9.1.
For example this is not useful for me: gcc -O3 -Q --help=optimizer
Because I don’t want to know what can be done, I want to know what is the default setting when I call gcc through CC.
What is cc going to add by default?